# To shuffle two list and merge into one list

Tags: r

I want to merge two list into one
  eg:

```
    A  B
    3  7
    1  8
    9  2
    31 4
```

Desired answer:

```
    A
    3
    8
    9
    4
```

It would be helpful if you anyone can tell me Code of this query?

Comment: What order is that? Where did `7` go?

Comment: Why is this the desired order? What are the rules with which you get to this order?

Comment: Hi, have you tried something so far, even if it is not working?

Comment: Using matrix subsetting: `x[cbind(1:nrow(x), 1:2)]`

Answer (score 1):

If `A` and `B` are vectors:

```
A[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- B[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
A
```

> ```
> [1] 3 8 9 4
> ```

If `A` and `B` are columns of a data frmae (which appears to be the case judging from the printed output)

```
DF$A[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- DF$B[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
DF
```

> ```
>   A B
> 1 3 7
> 2 8 8
> 3 9 2
> 4 4 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
A[seq(1:(length(A)/2))*2] <- B[seq(1:(length(A)/2))*2]
```